# group by time slots and plot calculated value vs. time slots

Tags: r, plot, time, group

I play an online card game with friends and keep a lot of statistics on the games.
Now I am interested to essentially evaluate if we play better or worse as it gets later in the evening. May actual dataset is much larger, but I use this example to illustrate:
I have a dataframe with two variables: a time variable (in hms format) and a logical vector showing  if a game played at that time was won (TRUE) or lost (FALSE).

```
library(hms)
win<-(c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE))
time<-as_hms(c("20:30:51","20:36:11","20:41:31","20:51:53","20:57:40","21:02:00","21:06:26","21:08:57","21:13:03","21:20:30","21:25:15","21:29:31","21:41:55","21:45:38","21:50:02","21:53:22","21:57:30","22:02:08"))
myframe <- data.frame(win, time)
```

Now I want to group the time, for example by hours, and calculate the win/loss ratio within these time slot: For example: There were five games played from 20-21 h, and 3 were won and 2 were lost. There were 12 games played from 21-22h of which 8 were won and 4 lost. Just one game after 22h, which was won.

I would like to have a plot with the time slots on the x-axis: 20-21h, 21-22h, 22-23h
And on the y axis I would like to plot the win ratio, that is 0.60, 0.67, 1.0.
I can calculate this ratio by sum(win==TRUE)/length(win). But how do I do this for defined time slots and then do such a plot?

I also want to be able to do this with customary, shorter, time slots, like 10 or 15 minutes. And be able to plot other data than just the win ratio vs. time slots.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  R has no built-in "time" class, so you will find life easier if you record the date as well as the time each game was played.  (You can extract time of day to help with your classification.)  The `lubridate` package has several functions and classes that will help you do what you want.  The `tidyverse` (meta)package includes a `group_by()` function that will allow you to calculate grouped summary statistics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the best option, but it can help you further.

```
library(tidyverse)
myframe %>%
  mutate(hour = sub("\\:.*", "", time),
         timeslot = ifelse(hour == "20", "20-21h",
                    ifelse(hour == "21", "21-22h", "22-23h"))) %>%
  group_by(timeslot) %>%
  mutate(win_ratio = sum(win == TRUE)/length(win)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = timeslot, y = win_ratio)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(y = "Win ratio") +
  theme_bw()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using `floor_hms` to round the time units:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridateExtras)
library(scales)
library(hms)

# Data
win <- c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
         TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)
time <- as_hms(c("20:30:51", "20:36:11", "20:41:31", "20:51:53", "20:57:40", 
          "21:02:00", "21:06:26", "21:08:57", "21:13:03", "21:20:30", "21:25:15", 
          "21:29:31", "21:41:55", "21:45:38", "21:50:02", "21:53:22", "21:57:30", "22:02:08"))
myframe <- data.frame(win, time)

# Plot
myframe |> 
  mutate(time = floor_hms(time, unit = "hour")) |> 
  group_by(time) |> 
  summarise(win_rate = sum(win) / n()) |> 
  ggplot(aes(time, win_rate)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_label(aes(label = percent(win_rate))) +
  scale_x_time() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = label_percent())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Carl, exactly what I needed! I had posted a "thank you" message already yesterday, even including my resulting graph. But my message has been deleted by an admin. Based on yours and the other responses I was quicky able to group by 15 min intervals and do the plot. Thanks again.